# R: Calculating cumulative returns with xts

Tags: r, xts

I'm importing several stock prices from CSV files with my own function readVariableAsXTS(VariableName). All the stock prices only have two columns, dates and prices. Now I want to create (obviously the code should be as fast as possible in doing that) an indexed version of these prices. So the NormalizedPrices[1] should be 100, NormalizedPrices[2] should be 100 * (1+VariableReturns[1]) or for the loop NormalizedPrices[i-1] * (1+VariableReturns[i]). However this always generates this error:

```
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : replacement has length Zero
```

And here's my complete function for the normalized prices:

```
getNormalizedPrices<-function(VariableName, InitialValue=100){
  VariableXTS<-readVariableAsXTS(VariableName)

  VariableReturns<-periodReturn(VariableXTS,period="daily",type="arithmetic")

  NormalizedPrices<-0*VariableReturns
  NormalizedPrices[1]<-InitialValue
  for(i in 2:nrow(VariableReturns)){
    NormalizedPrices[i]<-NormalizedPrices[i-1]*(1+VariableReturns[i])
  }

  VariableXTS[,1]<-NormalizedPrices[,1]
  return(VariableXTS)
}
```

I'm quite new to xts and R. So my three questions are:

1. Is there already a function for cumulative returns which I'm basically calculating here? I haven't found one in quantmod or PerformanceAnalytics.
2. Why is this error generated? As far as I've found answers to this questions, I assume I'm not able to work with xts and these [i-1] stuff
3. Should I convert this to vectors and back to make it faster?

Comment: Why not simply divide the prices by the first value, as in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654474/add-column-with-index-starting-at-100-to-stock-prices-returns-matrix/9654964#9654964)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly. However I don't understand this function. Why is the Matrix transposed twice and what does coredata do? I don't really understand the documenation for this...

Comment: `coredata` converts an `xts` object to a matrix (only the prices, without the dates). When dividing a matrix by a vector, the vector is converted to a matrix by recycling its elements column by column, often producing a matrix with identical columns -- when I want rows instead of columns, i.e., the same value in each column, I transpose the matrix before and after the computations.

Comment: Thx very much...learned a lot here!

Comment: Sorry still one last question..this function u is quite confusing. What is actually done here? function(u){ c(u[!is.na(u)&u!=0],NA)[1]

Comment: It returns the first non-missing and non-zero value of the vector of prices `u`: 
`!is.na(u)` is a boolean vector indicating the position of the non-missing values,
`u!=0`      is a boolean vector indicating the position of the non-zero values,
`u[!is.na(u)&u!=0]` is the vector of non-missing and non-zero values,
`c(...,NA)` ensures that the vector is non-empty,
and `[1]` extracts the first element.